# Integration by recurrence relation

Tags: calculus

For an integer $n \ge 0$, define

$I_n = \int_0^{\pi/8}\cos^{n+1}(2x)dx$.
Find a recurrence relation $I_n$ and $I_{n-2}$.

If someone could just give me a few hints in order to start this question. I don't want a solution just some hints so that I can figure it out myself, thank you.

Comment: Do you know integration by parts?

Comment: Yes, I do. I'm not sure how it can be applied here though.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to double-check all my arithmetic, but:

Integrating by parts with $u:=\cos^n(2x),\,v:=\tfrac12\sin(2x)$,$$I_n=2^{-(n+3)/2}+\int_0^{\pi/8}n\cos^{n-1}(2x)\sin^2(2x)dx=2^{-(n+3)/2}+n(I_{n-2}-I_n),$$since $\sin^2(2x)=1-\cos^2(2x)$. Rearranging, $I_n=\frac{nI_{n-2}+2^{-(n+3)/2}}{n+1}$.

Comment: Thank you, I understand how to do it now. Appreciate it!